# How can I Filtering and rename without renaming the unfiltered cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a very very large data set in a excel table format. I apply a filter to one of the variables and get the output.

There are multiple sub variables with the variable. I want to assign a common name to the groups of sub-variables.

For example, to all those values from o.012 to 16, I want to assign name "S"; to those between 31 & 64 I want to assign "I" and to those more than 65 I want to assign "R". There are some blank cells too.

What I do is I filter the required values in the column and in the next empty column to the right give the desired name of S, I or R. But unfortunately I get the names for the cells with blank values too or for the cells with other values. I mean I cannot apply the new name to the filtered cells only, why?

Answer (score 0):

Apply your First Filter

1. Select the Filtered Range which you want to give a Define Name
2. Click on GOTO Special in Editing Group, Home Tab
3. Click on the `VisibleCellsOnly`
4. OK
5. Write the Name in its place at the Left of fx in Address Bar
6. Enter
   Now clear the Filter, apply the new one and repeat the above steps 1-->6 use another Name
   Now you can use the Names as usual